# Increment values of a column based on the current row of another column and the previous row of the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

I want to create a column with multiple conditions wherein if the column ' Batt' contains 'Discharge' and the previous row contains 'none' then increment the value by 1 starting with 0 if not then return the same value without any increments.

> 

```
 Batt Disch            Continous Cycle count   
       None                0   
       None                0   
       Discharge           1  
       Discharge           1  
       None                1   
       Discharge           2  
       Discharge           2
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Do you want new values in the `Continous Cycle count` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can create a `boolean mask` and then use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to get the result:

```
df['Continous Cycle count'] = (
    (df['Batt Disch'].eq('Discharge') &
     df['Batt Disch'].shift().eq('None'))
    .cumsum()
)
```

Result:

```
  Batt Disch  Continous Cycle count
0       None                      0
1       None                      0
2  Discharge                      1
3  Discharge                      1
4       None                      1
5  Discharge                      2
6  Discharge                      2
```